# how to set up multiple computers full disk encryption?

Tags: security, encryption, filesystems

I want to set up my company's laptops in a way that all files created on these laptops can only read by these laptops. If it is copy to a usb then that file is only readable when plug that USB in a company laptop. If plug in or copy to another non-authorized laptop then it is not readable.

Earn and Young is using this technique to protect their data but I don't know what is it called and how to set it up. Please help :) thanks guy

Comment: That's definitely not what _full disk encryption_ means. Anyway, what you're trying to achieve is a DRM scheme and I doubt you'll be able to pull this off. Readable file is a copyable file.

Comment: The Bitlocker-to-go feature of Windows 10 may be of use to you. You can enforce it via GPO: https://techexpert.tips/windows/group-policy-to-force-usb-drive-encryption-on-removable-devices-bitlocker/